# Why is it recommended to include googletest source files

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, googlemock

Just a short and simple question,
Why is it recommended to compile googletest and googlemock within each project by including the source files (rather than using cmake to archive the library with a '.a' extension, then linking this to many projects).

source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/creating-google-test-run-debug-configuration-for-test.html

Comment: Seems like the recommendation there is based on a broken link. The google test FAQ doesn't contain such a recommendation anymore (not that I could find anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the '.a' file produced by googletest will differ depending on compiler flags.  Different test-projects that you want to make may set these differently, and this can cause problems if they reference a common googletest '.a' file.

From ['make install' considered harmful](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/googletestframework/Zo7_HOv1MJ0):

> In the README file for gtest and gmock, we said that you could install
>   compiled gtest and gmock libraries on *nix systems using 'make
>   install'.  Then every user of your machine can write tests without
>   recompiling gtest or gmock.
>
> This seemed like a good idea when we wrote the README, but it has a
>   got-cha: every user needs to compile his tests using the same compiler
>   flags used to compile the installed gtest/gmock libraries; otherwise
>   he may run into undefined behaviors (i.e. the tests can behave
>   strangely and may even crash for no obvious reasons).

Comment: even if we do accept the risk/ gotcha (say, because everyone on our project uses an identical build environment) we still need to add the include files to our project. Is that correct? Or is there a way to avoid that?
Secondly, given that docker usage is quite common now, isnt it normal to expect that users will want to spin up containers with well-defined compiler flags plus libraries so that engineers can focus on the coding aspects for the most part?